# Python - sort strings / numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

My problem, I would like to sort the below list (using Python)

`my_list = ['2', '1', '1+', '1-', '2+', '2-']`

into

`my_list = ['1+', '1', '1-', '2+', '2', '2-']`

**Edit:**

I tried `sorted` which gives me `['1', '1+', '1-', '2', '2+', '2-']`

Therefore, the order of '1' and '1+' should be changed, or '2+' and '2', etc. for all other numbers as well.

Comment: What did you try that did not work? I guess you already found `sorted` and [list.sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sort#list.sort)? In other words: can you be more specific with which part you are struggling?

Comment: I tried `sorted` which gives me `['1', '1+', '1-', '2', '2+', '2-']`, therefore, the order of '1' and '1+' should be changed, or '2+' and '2', etc. for all other numbers as well

Comment: Please add that to your question text. Also: it is still not clear what the *general* rule behind this sort order should be, as it seems quite arbitrary? How should this sort rule  handle multi-digit numbers (`'1234+', '1234', '1234-'`)? The example so far looks quite random

Comment: The rule is: any number with a "+" at the end, then any number without an additional character, then any number with "-" at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arbitrary rules call for an arbitrary expendable solution: I am relying on the fact that tuples sort element by element, so the numbers `0`, `1`, `2` serve as priorities:

```
def plus_before_minus(item):
    number = item.rstrip('+-')
    if item.endswith('+'):
        return (number, 0)
    elif item.endswith('-'):
        return (number, 2)
    else:
        return (number, 1)
```

with that, the list sorts as required:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=plus_before_minus)
['1+', '1', '1-', '2+', '2', '2-']
```

Comment: Could also use `number = item.rstrip("+-")` :)

Comment: @swenzel: Yes, thanks, where was my head?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I am firstly creating a function `get_priority` to return the priority of each element. This returned number will be later used for sorting.

```
def get_priority(x):
    return {
        '+': 1,
        '-': 3
    }.get(x, 2)

# If returned number:
#     ends with '-': return 3 (Highest / First)
#     ends with '+': return 1 (Lowest / Last)
#     else: return 2 (Medium / Middle)
```

Then here I am going to use `get_priority` function along with [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to achieve your desired order as:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

my_list = ['2', '1', '1+', '1-', '2+', '2-']

new_list = [i for _, l in groupby(sorted(my_list), key=itemgetter(0)) for i in sorted(l, key= lambda x: get_priority(x[-1]))]
```

where `new_list` will return you the value:

```
['1+', '1', '1-', '2+', '2', '2-']
```